# BL InitializeLibrary failed 0XC0000185 Error while booting to 19H1

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader, bios, uefi

Getting below Error while booting to 19H1 windows UEFI OS:
"BL InitializeLibrary failed 0XC0000185"
How can the same traced from efi boot loader bootx64.efi? how can we capture logs of bootx64.efi?

Answer (score 0):

First this is a common issue (the `BL` stands for bootloader), see https://www.lifewire.com/fix-error-code-0xc0000185-4691254

Possible paths to debug UEFI are listed in https://ami.com/ami_downloads/Intel_Technology_Journal_Debugging_Firmware_Based_on_the_UEFI.pdf

You could try if your machine has a USB debug port (https://www.coreboot.org/EHCI_Debug_Port) or enable UEFI strings or, what is best, search for the JTAG port of your motherboard (https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/emiribric/jtag-interface-as-a-tool-for-repairing-various-types-of-motherboards-part-2-062619)

Comment: what could be the reasons which can cause this issue? I am seeing this issue randomly during frequent reboot.

Comment: In https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-blinitializelibrary-failed-0xc00000bb-error-on-windows/ is a list of potential causes, however as windows is closed source it is hard to find the deeper reasons

Comment: This looks like EDKII AHCI driver issue, any idea on this issue with existing EDKII code?